# MYSQL Replace string that contains specific substring

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, regex-replace

Basically, I want to substring all strings that contain the word COMPRIMIDO to keep only COMPRIMIDO

Example:

| medication_title | medication_type | medication_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ZYTIGA 500 MG | COMPRIMIDO REVESTIDO | COMPRIMIDO |
| VERZENIOS 50 MG | COMPRIMIDO MOLE | COMPRIMIDO |

I tried using `replace` function:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(medication_type, 'COMPRIMIDO REVESTIDO', 'COMPRIMIDO'), 'COMPRIMIDO MOLE', 'COMPRIMIDO') as medication_result
```

But I think there are easier ways to do this, especially thinking about situations where we can have several string variations with "COMPRIMIDO"

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to use a case expression with LIKE.

```
select medication_title, medication_type, 
 case 
  when upper(medication_type) like '%COMPRIMIDO%' then 'COMPRIMIDO' 
  else medication_type 
 end medication_result
from my_data
```